# Very slow application of ACL Policies with the open source rundeck

Tags: acl, rundeck

I'm running 3.3.10 of the open source version of Rundeck and use a multi auth approach with Active Directory and local users. That's behaving fine.

When I update an aclpolicy (either through the UI or directly on the filesystem) for any user (local or AD) it can take hours to apply the new acl. It eventually does apply which would indicate to me something internal to rundeck.

It's not isolated to a single instance either. It's happening on multiple instances. Has anyone else seen this occur? From reading the documentation it would indicate that the ACL's should apply relatively quickly.

Comment: Hi! Still happening if you add the ACL as "Stored ACL Policies"?

Comment: I've never used those. These are standalone rundeck instances. Should all the ACL's be moved to "Stored ACL Policies"? This only seems to have become an issue in the past few minor versions of 3.3.x

Comment: I did some quick tests there and it looks like the issue is also present using the "Stored ACL Policies". If I log out/in again it seems to work. Which is a big improvement

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your issue. How many ACLs are you using in your instance? Maybe that's the cause of the slowness.

Comment: Varies between 3-10 on a given instance. We don't use project ACL's at all. Moving the existing ACL's to the "Stored ACL Policies" seems to have sorted the issue. I'll just need to migrate all the existing policies to use that going forward. 

Thanks for the steer by the way.